# Apostrophes in Dynamic Data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, htmlspecialchars

I have the simple need of allowing users to enter an apostrophe into various fields that will be saved to a MySQL table via PHP. When a user looks at this information, I would like it to be echoed out without a /. What is the best way to handle this. Below are my ideas:

- set stripslashes when echoing out content
- Convert the apostrophe to "'" back and forth

I am also running mysql_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars on the posted data. Is there a standardized way of handling this? Thank you!

Comment: That's most likely due to your magic_quotes settings, just disable it. As for the escaping, m_r_e_s() is fine, but a better approach would be to use prepared statements (look into mysqli or PDO)

Comment: Damien is right.PDO and mysqli are best for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) for entering apostrophe and as you have already said use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) for echoing.
Use `addslashes()` only if you want to add apostrophes for more escaping functions used `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() already takes care of quotes, allowing for safe insertion. Why using addslashes?

Comment: Well Damien, I would always prefer `mysql_real_escape_string` over `addslashes` but in this case he just want to escape apostrophes, so I have mentioned `addlslahes`, also `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't necessarily add slashes to escape, recent versions of MySQL escape quotes by putting two of them together instead of by putting a slash before it.

Comment: the point is, escaping functions due their work at sql time, and don't affect the content. So mysql_real_escape or the doubling of quotes you mention only happen during insertion, but inside the database the content is normal. Addslashes, instead, "physically" adds slashes, which then you need to remove from the text - that's a reason why your solution is kinda wrong.

Comment: @DamienPirsy, Thanks Damien. It sounds like using m_r_e_s() is OK to use when put data into the db, and that stripslashes is OK to use when echoing it out. Thanks!